# Can I install Ubuntu before Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I ordered Lenovo desktop PC M710t, which is freeDOS OS.

Usually Windows is installed first, and Ubuntu after for dual boot.

Can I switch the OS installation order?

Because I haven't purchased Windows 10 OS yet.

Comment: I marked this for closure with a link to an older question about doing the same thing - it can be done, *but* there will be some problems.

Comment: Since you have a desktop PC, unlike the OP of the linked question, there's also the option of installing Windows on a separate HDD (change the boot order or disconnect the other HDD first, then change it back after the installation is done). That way you can keep both bootloaders intact, with no need to repair grub. Also probably less risk of Windows updates messing something up later. (Haven't tried this with Windows 10, but it works well with Win7, at least.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I switch the OS installation order?

Yes.

You usually install Windows 1st because the last installed OS uses its bootloader to take presedence. And our grub adds Windows. Windows though does not add other operating systems.

But you could always install Windows last and use a tool like boot-repair to install Grub.

Nowadays we use (U)EFI. And there the boot is done by creating a little bit of room on the disk where you install a file that points to an operating system. So the order does not matter anymore: you tell inside the BIOS you want to install an OS and it will add your OS to the EFI.

So yes. Totally possible.